# Powershell variable starts with @ and ends with @

Tags: powershell, variables

studing things about powershell and looking at examples I saw that a variable can starts with an @ after = and ends with @ but can't find anything related to this in the official documentation of microsoft, can someone explain me this?

I paste you an example of how does it look (I cut some parts to show the @).

```
$htmlBody = @"
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>     
"@
```

Comment: It's called a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#here-strings).

Comment: It's called a here-string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#here-strings

Comment: Wow, thanks for your fast answer! Couldn't find the documentation tiping thing like "variable @" or "variable with @", now I know how its called. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

It's a string literal (a piece of code that produces a string), not a variable (an association between a name and a piece of memory).

Knowing this, we easily find the reference on [quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2) (First match on Google for *PowerShell string literals*.)

The [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#here-strings) titled "Here-strings" describes this syntax. Here it is in part:

> A here-string can have either of the following formats, where  represents the linefeed or newline hidden character that is added when you press the ENTER key.
>
> Double-quotes:
>
> ```
> @"<Enter>
> <string> [string] ...<Enter>
> "@
> ```
>
> Single-quotes:
>
> ```
> @'<Enter>
> <string> [string] ...<Enter>
> '@
> ```
>
> In either format, the closing quotation mark must be the first character in the line.
>
> A here-string contains all the text between the two hidden characters. In the here-string, all quotation marks are interpreted literally. For example:
> PowerShell
>
> ```
> @"
> For help, type "get-help"
> "@
> ```
>
> The output of this command is:
>
> ```
> For help, type "get-help"
> ```